# want to reset values after some time using scheduler or db event

Tags: scheduled-tasks, scheduler, spring-scheduled

I have a jsp like:

rule 1 : value

rule 2 : value

Time interval in min :value

I am saving these values to DB
depending on the value of time interval field I want to reset the value of rule 1 and rule 2 to a default value in DB

This time interval can be changed any time even before previous interval is not completed,means it needs to be updated dynamically whatever approach I choose

I am using Sprig MVC and oracle
I opted for 
ThreadPoolTaskScheduler

but now problem is as soon as I used

threadPoolTaskScheduler.schedule(runnableObj,trigger);

it is getting executed immediately and then executes on proper interval of  1 min but I want to skip first execution for that I have used PeriodicTrigger
which has method named setInitialDelay() but it is not delaying it

Please provide some insight for this kind of problems as I am doing it first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it using ThreadPoolTaskScheduler
For more info visit http://www.baeldung.com/spring-task-scheduler
Some interesting Spring Scheduling information.